# How to access the body of a custom element from within a Polymer template?

Tags: templates, interpolation, polymer

I have a custom Polymer element `<foo>`. In its `<template>` element, how can I access the body of the `<foo>` element? That is, how do I arrange for:

```
<foo>
  <em>Clem</em>
</foo>
```

to be transformed into

```
Hello, <em>Clem</em>
```

via a `<template>` that will presumably look something like

```
<polymer-element name="foo">
  <template>
    Hello, ???
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: More or less the same question, but expressed in a more straightforward way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376947/custom-polymer-element-x-strong-that-works-like-the-builtin-strong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ebidel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274673/ebidel) points out in [Custom Polymer element <x-strong> that works like the builtin <strong>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376947/custom-polymer-element-x-strong-that-works-like-the-builtin-strong), you'll need to create an insertion point with the `<content>` tag.

I should also point out that your element name needs to contain a dash to meet the spec. So it  should be `<x-foo>` or `<my-foo>`, not just `<foo>`.