# Custom Polymer element <x-strong> that works like the builtin <strong>?

Tags: polymer

How do you create a custom element such as `<x-strong>` that works like the builtin `<strong>`?

I've got as far as the following:

```
<polymer-element name="x-strong" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      x-strong {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    ???
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

HTML:

```
<x-strong>Hello, <em>Clem</em></x-strong> 
// Would like this to render exactly the same as
<strong>Hello, <em>Clem</em></strong>
```

However, this has at least two problems:

1. I don't know how to get at the contents/children of the `<x-strong>` element. (All of [the examples](http://www.polymer-project.org/getting-started.html#publishing-properties) I've found show how to access attributes from the custom element, but not its content.)
2. For some reason the CSS selector within the `<style>` element needs to be `x-strong`--`body`, `html` and `*` all don't work.

Adding/removing the `lightdom` and `noscript` attributes modify the behaviour in slightly different ways, but no combination seems to replicate the builtin element. Extending `<strong>` also doesn't work (although I actually want to do this from scratch, as an exercise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render content from the light dom into your Polymer element's shadow use an [insertion point](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation): `<content>`. Also to style the host element, you can use the `:host` selector. Both are features of Shadow DOM.

```
<polymer-element name="x-strong" noscript>
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  <content></content>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/EqaxOTo/1/edit